# Stack row 2x2 on Bootstrap using rows in same height... how?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My issue started on my need to have a nice row with same height in any device using Bootstrap 3. So far ok... I googled it and found this code here

```
/* Row with equal height columns */
.row-eq-height {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

So far so good. But, in mobile device doesn't look so good... so, I searched a little bit more and found my answers [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Well, my code at the end is this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tofanelli/full/QbyWMP). Works? Yeah.... kind of.... What I want is, when possible, the row stacks in a 2x2 column, like this image

[image]

Like this one

in small tablet portrait mode (600x800) and not like this one i am getting

[image]

The first image has less words than the second one just to show how I want them.

Well, and there is another issue too... If you look into the code on Codepen, this CSS ONLY works, for any reason, if I leave second } closing the "container" on styles....

Yeah.... so many issues in only one thread.... so, to summarize:

1. why do I need to leave that second `}` to make this works?
2. If I don't need it, how to make this works then?
3. How to make the columns stacks on 2x2 when small tablet portrait mode?

To help me to see the responsive resolutions, I use a Chrome add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using bootstrap at all, you can use `flex-wrap: wrap` to wrap the cells that don't fit. Flex will still respect `min-width` and `max-width`, so you can use those to determine the width.

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row-eq-height > div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row-eq-height > div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-eq-height">
  <div style="background-color:#F89406;">Col 1
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.</div>
  <div style="background-color:#00B16A;">Col 2
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.</div>
  <div style="background-color:#4183D7;">Col 3
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.</div>
  <div style="background-color:#F64747;">Col 4
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.</div>
</div>
```

An alternative is to use `flex-basis` to determine the width. Leaving `flex-basis` at the default of `0` means it will treat it as having no width, and will stretch them all to fit. If you set the basis to `50%`, that says it should take up half the container if it can. Since it's set to wrap, it can go ahead and take up half the screen and push the other elements to the next row. If you had `flex-wrap: nowrap` it would shrink them down to about 25% instead. You could then use different media queries to force the `flex-basis` to be a different size.

For some reason, setting `flex-basis: 50%` doesn't work when using bootstrap. There must be some conflicting CSS that makes `50%` actually take up slightly more than half of the container.

The code is a messier for this method because you need to specify each media query. I'd recommend the `min-width` method because it's cleaner and easier, but here's an example using `flex-basis` and media queries just in case:

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row-eq-height > div {
  flex: 1;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .row-eq-height > div {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .row-eq-height > div {
    flex-basis: 33%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .row-eq-height > div {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .row-eq-height > div {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row-eq-height > div {
  flex: 1;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .row-eq-height > div {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .row-eq-height > div {
    flex-basis: 33%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .row-eq-height > div {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .row-eq-height > div {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row-eq-height">
  <div style="background-color:#F89406;">Col 1
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.</div>
  <div style="background-color:#00B16A;">Col 2
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.</div>
  <div style="background-color:#4183D7;">Col 3
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.</div>
  <div style="background-color:#F64747;">Col 4
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.
    <br/>Add your content here.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is almost answered.... i might forgot the mention, in the mobile view (portrait or landscape) I wish to keep as it was, stacked, so everything there will be more comfortable to read and click.

Mind to give me a hand?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The example I gave stacks them (2 columns, 2 rows) when you're in a small screen, and shows them all in one row (4 columns) when you're in a larger screen. Is that not what you were wanting?

Comment: hey @redbmk.... in small screen sizes, i want them stacked and tablets / phablets / desktops  as 2x2.... from this point is it easier to get them?

Comment: Sure, you could modify the basis to be 100% for screen sizes where you want it to be full width, 50% for 2x2, 33% for 3 in a row, etc. I'm not at my computer right now but I'll modify the answer to reflect that later

Comment: man... you are THE MAN!!! completely solved and worked as I really wanted =)

Thanks very much =)